# Is \p{L} equivalent to [^\d\s]

Tags: regex, pcre

To match letters are these two regular expressions equivalent? Is one generally more preferable? Or is this a case of "it depends"?

1.Unicode letter short code:

```
\p{L}
```

2.Negated `PCRE` short codes for digits and whitespaces:

```
[^\d\s]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not equivalent.

Assuming you use the `u` option, `\p{L}` means "letter (Category L)". `[^\s\d]` means "not a whitespace (Category Z), and not a digit (Category Nd)". ***If*** every character indeed belongs to one of the three categories, then you'd be right because of set theory, but there are characters that do not belong to any of the three categories.

The comma `,` for example, is a *punctuation* (Category P), and will be matched by `[^\s\d]`, but not `\p{L}`.

[In fact, there are a *lot* more than 3 categories in Unicode.](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)

So to actually use a negation to represent `\p{L}`, you'd have to say:

```
[^\p{C}\p{M}\p{N}\p{P}\p{S}\p{Z}]
```

basically listing all other categories. But it will break as soon as Unicode decides to add a new category and PCRE decides to support it. Needless to say, please don't use it in production :)

Answer (score 1):

The contrast between the two regexes is stark:

The regex `\p{L}` matches any *letter* (hence the `L`), not only of the Roman and the Greek alphabet, as `\w` does, but also of any other alphabet.

The negated character class `[^\d\s]` matches anything that is *not* a number `0-9` and not a tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, space and possibly other locale-dependent characters.

So, `[^\d\s]` is far more powerful, matching a far greater range of character types, than `\p{L}`, which matches just one type of characters.

Comment: cheers Chris - "powerful" could really be either angle - maybe the focus of \p{L} is power?